# The explanation of Sunan Ibn Majah 537

Tags: hadith-interpretation

As we all know how these kuffars keep cherry picking hadith without any further information. I want the explanation of the hadith (Sunan Ibn Majah 537) - it was about our mother, Aisha (RA) washed off the semen from prophet Muhammad (SAW) garment and they (kuffars) deem this to be some sort of awful things or whatever their dirty mind could ever wonder. So please help me understand this further, JazakAllah Khair.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q &A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. As none of the author's of Hadith collections enumerated their books or ahadith these numbers are not agreed upon so please share the Hadith you are referring to in best case in the Arabic original wording. Else you leave us guessing which Hadith you are referring to.